# Decode the original URL

Tags: php, url

I want to decode some of the url into their original URL. Current URL are in the following formats.

```
http://www.1channel.ch/external.php?`title=The+Pursuit+of+Happyness&url=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5wdXRsb2NrZXIuY29tL2ZpbGUvRkNFRkNBMUI4RTMwQk`Y3OQ==&domain=cHV0bG9ja2VyLmNvbQ==&loggedin=1
```

I want to do this with some php code. Please help me out. I'll be really thankful.

Comment: maybe you want encode, try to use urlencode(), urldecode()

Comment: echo $_GET['url']; ouput will be: aHR0cDovL3d3dy5wdXRsb2NrZXIuY29tL2ZpbGUvRkNFRkNBMUI4RTMwQk`Y3OQ== it looks like base64, make echo base64_decode($_GET['url']); and so on :]

Comment: Open this URL results into a 302 Moved Temporarily to http://www.putlocker.com/file/FCEFCA1B8E30BF79. Do you mean you want to know how to get this URL out of the url you provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `url` parameter is ran through `base64_encode`. Something like this should work.

```
$url = "http://www.1channel.ch/external.php?`title=The+Pursuit+of+Happyness&url=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5wdXRsb2NrZXIuY29tL2ZpbGUvRkNFRkNBMUI4RTMwQk`Y3OQ==&domain=cHV0bG9ja2VyLmNvbQ==&loggedin=1";

$params = explode('&', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY));

foreach($params as $param)
{
    $a = explode('=', $param);
    if($a[0] === "url")
    {
        echo base64_decode($a[1]);
        break 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very witty, I didn't realize the url parameter was in Base64. The result is http://www.putlocker.com/file/FCEFCA1B8E30BF79, the url it redirects to.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use urldecode, as you can see in [function urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).